# Shopping Cart Price Rule for selected items in one category

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules

I was requested to create a Cart Price Rule which applies a discount of $10 to a shopping cart containing some items from one category. In this sub-category, I have 80 different items but only 15 of them will have my discount.

I've configured the Conditions as below:

[image]

*As you can see, I tried 2 different rules.*

And the Actions as below :

[image]

I just want to have $10 off some products, but the rest of the cart won't have any discount. When I follow the steps above, nothing happens in my cart. HELP!!

I'm using Magento ver. 2.4.5-p1.

Thank you!!
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Did you try these steps for applying the rule?

To create a Cart Price Rule that applies a discount of $10 to a shopping cart containing some items from one category, and only 15 of them will have the discount, follow these steps:

Go to Marketing > Cart Price Rules in the Magento Admin Panel.

1. Click Add New Rule.
2. Enter a name for your rule in the Rule Information section.
3. Set the Status to Active.
4. Choose the Websites and Customer Groups that will be eligible for the discount.
5. In the Conditions section, click the + button to add a new condition.
6. Choose the Product attribute combination condition.
7. Click the green plus button to add a new condition line.
8. Choose the Category attribute and select the category that contains the products that will be eligible for the discount.
9. Click the green plus button to add another condition line.
10. Choose the Product attribute and select the list of 15 products that will be eligible for the discount.
11. Set the condition operator to "is one of".
12. In the Actions section, set Apply to "Percent of product price discount" and set Discount Amount to 10.
13. Save the rule.

After following these steps, when a customer adds one or more eligible products to their cart, they will see the discount applied to the subtotal of the order. If the discount is not applied, ensure that the products are correctly assigned to the category and the product list, and that the rule is active and meets all the conditions.